# How can I make pseudo-element background align with parent's background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this simple container, and generated some vertical stripes to use as background.

```
export default function App() {
  return <div className="container"></div>;
}
```

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #000000 12.5%,
    #ffffff 12.5%,
    #ffffff 50%,
    #000000 50%,
    #000000 62.5%,
    #ffffff 62.5%,
    #ffffff 100%
  );
  background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
  position: relative;
}
```

I want to create a pointer (arrow), that is positioned at the top, or bottom, but that has the same background as the parent. And no matter which value I give to `left` or `right`, it should have the stripes aligned with the parent's.

Right now, I have this code for the pseudo-element.

```
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: inherit;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  left: 27px;
}
```

But as you can see in the Sandbox below, the stripes are not aligned correctly of the `.container`, I mean, they do not come as "continuation" of the said background. Is there a possible trick I can make it part of the same background?

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-browser-tnt8zq

Here's also a picture for reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/emU7g.png

The stripes should blend like this, no matter where the arrow is positioned horizontally.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nlxn.png

Comment: Why not just make it transparent?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't see how that would work. If it's transparent, then it'll be just blending to the white background?

Comment: background-attachment: fixed on .container and background: inherit on .container: after?

Comment: @Taras, this is ingenious but background-attachment: fixed can present problems on IOS (not sure whether it would create a problem in this instance).

Answer (score 2):

Use This code

```
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #000000 12.5%,
    #ffffff 12.5%,
    #ffffff 50%,
    #000000 50%,
    #000000 62.5%,
    #ffffff 62.5%,
    #ffffff 100%
  );
  background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
  position: relative;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: inherit;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  left: 48%;
  top:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make things quite flexible, easy to change, by using CSS variables.

This snippet scraps the pseudo element, makes the container a bit bigger and cuts out the shape required. The way you are assured of getting the correctly aligned background.

Set the width, height and distance along the left of the pointy bit as you require in those CSS variables.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  --aH: 25px;
  /* height of the arrow */
  --aW: 25px;
  /* width of the arrow */
  --aL: 27px;
  /* distance along the top of the start of the arrow */
  --h: 200px;
  /* height of container */
  height: calc(var(--h) + var(--aH));
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, #000000 12.5%, #ffffff 12.5%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 62.5%, #ffffff 62.5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--aH), var(--aL) var(--aH), calc(var(--aL) + (var(--aW) / 2)) 0, calc(var(--aL) + var(--aH)) var(--aH), 100% var(--aH), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

UPDATE: there is a requirement to have the container height fixed by its content, not a px value. This snippet is as above except the background image and its associated clip path is put onto the container's before pseudo element. That way it can pick up the height of the container and add further height to accommodate the arrow.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  --aH: 25px;
  /* height of the arrow */
  --aW: 25px;
  /* width of the arrow */
  --aL: 27px;
  /* distance along the top of the start of the arrow */
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  --h: 100%;
  /* height of container */
  height: calc(var(--h) + var(--aH));
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(calc(-1 * var(--aH)));
  background-color: pink;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, #000000 12.5%, #ffffff 12.5%, #ffffff 50%, #000000 50%, #000000 62.5%, #ffffff 62.5%, #ffffff 100%);
  background-size: 11.31px 11.31px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--aH), var(--aL) var(--aH), calc(var(--aL) + (var(--aW) / 2)) 0, calc(var(--aL) + var(--aH)) var(--aH), 100% var(--aH), 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br>some stuff<br></div>
```

Comment: Hmm, the thing is, I've added height on the .container just to illustrate my diagonal stripes. In my project, the height is given by the content that .container holds. So, would this solution be applicable even when we don't know the height of the .container?

Comment: Yes, I've added a further snippet. This puts the background onto the before pseudo element as that way it can be set to the height of the container plus the height of the arrow.

Comment: I see. Looks good, however, re-calculating these paths will be a real pain in the ass, because sometimes the arrow is at the top, sometimes it's on the right side, or at the bottom, etc. Not to say that the requirement is that the arrow should point in the middle of the element it's directed at, so I can use this .container and above it, a button. The arrow then should point at the button.

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult. you need to add some CSS variables to say where the arrow is to be vertically and so on. However, how automatic do you want it to be? i.e. at what point do you know that the thing you want pointed to is to the left or above or whatever?

Comment: Well, considering that this is supposed to be a component delivered in a library package, I will probably not know, only the consumer using this package will, which is why I want to make it as flexible as possible, so it's ready to be used without any adjustments to the styles.

I have looked at react-popper for helping position the arrow related to an element, but I am not sure if I'm being able to define the element as the pseudo-element I'd be using here.

Comment: What I meant was, could there be for example a class 'toparrow' and another one 'rightarrow' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We can play with clip-path values and position left values to get the desire outcome.

please try with below code.

```
.container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: inherit;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 95%);
  left: 20px;
}
```